# Including entity code in link_to_function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anyway to include an entity code (→ for instance) in the link_to_function helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
<%= link_to_function raw("Run this &rarr;"), "alert('Run!')" %>
```

To be honest: I have no idea why "Run this →" is treated as an unsafe string...

Comment: If its rails 3.2 then that it is because unsafe is the new standard. http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Comment: This is only unsafe if you display possibly unsafe data from your database: `<%= link_to raw("Comment: #{comment.title}"), comment %>`; If you only display static HTML this is perfectly fine. What would be your counter proposal?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe I was unclear,  I meant to say that rather then pre Rails 3(I think) the standard assumption was safe, thus nothing was escaped unless the `h` tag was there. In the current version of Rails the reverse is true, everything is escaped unless it is `.html_safe` or `raw`.